# Fail to renewcommand contentsname if \pagesty{fancy} is introduced

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec, titletoc

When I customize the `\contentsname` with `\renewcommand`, I find that the existence of `\pagestyle{fancy}` or `\thispagestyle{fancy}` will cause compile fail. I can't understand this. why? Is this a problem of `\contentsname` or of the package `fancyhdr`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{fancy}% This command leads to un-compiled. If this command is commented, or replaced by\pagestyle{plain}, everyting is all right.
  \renewcommand\contentsname{%
    \LARGE%
    \centering%
       my\\ content%
  }
  \tableofcontents

\section{section}
text

\end{document}
```

PS: I find that macros related to position like `\centering`, `\\` are the failure reason. Other macros not related to position like `\color`, `\Large` don't affect \renewcommand\contentsname.

[image]

Comment: It is wrong to use font changes to the name to start with. What are you trying to achieve? Centered chapter heads in your document?

Comment: `\contentsname` should contain only the name of the Table of Contents, since it is used e.g. also in the headline, while a different formatting should be achieved using specialized packages (e.g. `titlesec`).

Comment: Contentsname is a name, not a formatting instruction. Don't add things like centering or large to it.

Comment: Normally, the title of a tableofcontent is "`Contents`". I want ot change the text("My Contents in this example) and its style, like `\large, \color `etc. But if there is fancy, it fails. Without fancy, I can do nealy everythig on `\contentsname`

Comment: @zetaeffe There are conflictions between titlesec and fancyhdr as pointed in site.

Comment: Even if you can you shouldn't -- the problem with fancyhdr shows why.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer So it's a problem of `fancyhdr`? I don't see it in the document of fancyhdr. And there are no other  better methods to modify `contentsname` if `macros from fancyhdr` is in?

Comment: It is simply wrong to add anything but a name. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to change the size of the chapter headers, or the alignment or the color, have a look at package `titlesec`.

Comment: The change of the name will occur in the whole document. Also the headers, which are suddenly colored and in different size.

Comment: @ Johannes_B I only intend to change the typeset style of the TOC header text from "Contents" to "My Content" and its font size, color, position etc. I don't care about "chapter heads".

Comment: The head of the TOC is a chapter head. Unnumbered chapter. Just like the list of figures/tables and the bibliography or index or any starred chapter.

Comment: Thank you@Johannes_B @zetaeffe It's until today doI know from you the meaning of TOC header. I triid to modify the chapter format like this(copy from the titlesec document, but change color), `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\color{blue}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{my\\ content}{20pt}{\Huge}` but it does not work.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,titlesec,xcolor}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{fancy}% This command leads to un-compiled. If this command is commented, or replaced by\pagestyle{plain}, everyting is all right.
   \renewcommand\contentsname{%
       My \\ content%
}
{
\titleformat*{\section}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}\centering \LARGE\color{red}}
  \tableofcontents
}
\section{section}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really what I want! Many thanks. And why \titleformat*, not \titleformat?

Comment: @lyl `\titleformat*` is a light version of the more advanced command `\titleformat`. In this cas as you can see  it is sufficient to use `\titleformat*`. Now if you ask why the command `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\color{blue}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{my\\ content}{20pt}{\Huge}` does not work? At first glance I would said that is because in `\documentclass{article}` there is no chapters

Comment: Your answer and comments perfectly disabuse me. Many thanks!!

Comment: @lyl You are welcome! and I am very happy that your problem has been solved.